# Are infinitesimals still being used in calculus?

Tags: calculus

When Newton and Leibniz used invented calculus they used infinitesimals. Karl Weierstrass rid the use of infinitesimals in 1870 with the (ε, δ)-definition of limit. But my math teacher told us that some mathematicians still use infinitesimals. Why still use infinitesimals?

Comment: Recommended: first read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis then come back and ask us any questions beyond that.

Comment: Infinitesimals are banished from a standard rigorous development of calculus, because it's difficult to make them precise. But "infinitesimal intuition" is simple, clear, makes calculus seem obvious, and is at the heart of understanding calculus, in my opinion.

Comment: I suppose one must differentiate between the use of infinitesimals as a foundation for calculus, and the use of infinitesimals when reasoning about applications. That the derivative maps an infinitesimal change in the domain to one in the codomain, or that the area form represents the area of an infinitesimal paralellogram, are extremely fruitful ideas practically and pedagogically, and do not require a formal foundation built on nonstandard analysis etc.

Comment: @littleO: the idea of infinitesimals appears very counter-intuitive to me. I just can not imagine a number which is non-zero and still less than all positive numbers. The idea of an Archimedean field appears to be so natural in the sense that it says that one can measure large lengths using a small ruler. But I agree some people might find infinitesimals more psychologically appealing.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Oh, I agree with that completely, perhaps the way I said that was unclear. When I see arguments involving infinitesimals, I convert them into arguments involving extremely tiny but finite numbers, and I replace the equals signs with approximately equals signs, and once we derive a formula that holds approximately I hope that "in the limit" the approximate equality will turn into exact equality.

Comment: For example, my intuitive understanding of the fundamental theorem of calculus is to chop up the interval $[a,b]$ into tiny (but finite) subintervals $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ of width $\Delta x$, and then note that $f(b) - f(a) = \sum_i f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i) \approx \sum_i f'(x_i) \Delta x \approx \int_a^b f'(x) \, dx$. . That's the kind of intuition I refer to as "infinitesimal intuition".

Comment: @littleO : got it. When I started learning calculus I went through that sort of reasoning in many books, but i wasn't happy/satisfied until I got all those things proved in Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics*. I always wondered "what if these ideas did not have a solid basis" but luckily it turned out that they did have rigorous justification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinitesimals are also still used in Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis where you need to work in a constructive logic (ie, no use of excluded middle or axiom of choice in your arguments). See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis)

Why use them?  If we assume the Kock-Lawvere axiom holds, properties of derivatives become almost trivial. A lot of geometric intuition about derivatives can be made rigorous by assuming infinitesimals exist. There is also no need to talk about sequences and limits to define derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

As GEdgar states in the comments, people studying non-standard analysis still use infinitesimals.

If you're interested, I recommend the book: 
Arkeryd, Cutland and Henson: Nonstandard Analysis, Theory and Applications